# Regex match through multiple lines

Tags: c#, .net, regex

For example we have following string:

```
Something
AnotherThing
Something AnotherThing
```

If I use `RegexOptions.Singleline` with pattern `Something.+?AnotherThing` then I get two matches when I want to match first and second lines only. I want to use something like `FirstLine#endofline##startofline#AnotherLine`. So i use:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Something$^AnotherThing", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

but it doesn't work. I know that I can use some hack with Singleline to match first two lines (and not the last one), but the question: Is it even possible to match exact two texts in exact 2 lines without Singleline specifier, with Multiline option only? And why does it behaves like this.

Comment: You can try `^(Something[\s]+AnotherThing)`..

Comment: It will match the last line too. See marked answer, it fulfill my needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
Something\r?\nAnotherThing
```

`\r?` in case the string doesn't come from Windows.

The reason `Something$^AnotherThing` doesn't work with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, is because `^` and `$` match *at* line breaks, not the line breaks themselves, so the following would work:

```
new Regex(@"Something$\r?\n^AnotherThing", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: `$\r?\n^` will work if there's only a linefeed (`\n`), but not if there's a carriage return as well (`\r\n`).  .NET is unique among the Perl-derived regex flavors in that it recognizes **only** `\n` as a line separator (the Unicode standard is [much more inclusive](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Line_Boundaries)).  But whichever flavor you're using, if you have to match the line separators anyway, `^` and `$` are just clutter.

Comment: It's been a while but I just noticed your comment @AlanMoore. Can you explain "$\r?\n^ will work if there's only a linefeed (\n), but not if there's a carriage return as well (\r\n)."? AFAICS, that should match both, that's the whole purpose of `\r?`.

Comment: It's because `$` expects to see a linefeed (in Multiline mode) or the end of the text.  If the next character is a carriage return, the end of the line hasn't been reached, so `$` fails to match.  Again, this applies to .NET only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to match using the carriage return and line break characters, e.g.

```
Something\r?\nAnotherThing
```

Basically, carriage returns are causing you trouble (you're not alone). Do you know which OS your text is coming from? If it's from Windows then there will be a \r before the \n, which you need to account for.

Comment: `\r$` doesn't work in this case for the same reason `$^` didn't work: you need to *consume* the linefeed, but `$` merely asserts that it's there.